# It is known that apache resolves foo.com even if as named virtual host only beta.foo.com exists?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

The only virtual hosts i have are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
    # etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/beta.foo.com/htdocs
ServerName beta.foo.com

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/www.foo.com/htdocs/>
    Options All -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog  /var/www/vhosts/www.foo.com/logs/error.log
LogLevel debug  
CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/www.foo.com/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

`beta.foo.com` is perfectly reachable, and that's the expected behaviour.

But when i try to get `www.foo.com`, it resolves to `beta.foo.com` and not to the `default` configuration.

Is this an Apache rule?

Is there a way to avoid this?

The only way is to set a virtual host with ServerName `www.foo.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation explains [how the virtual host is chosen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html#hostmatching). Basically, your `beta.foo.com` host is chosen because it has a specific IP address, whereas the default host uses a wildcard. Either change your `beta.foo.com` block to also use a wildcard, or change your default host to use the specific IP.